# Store function not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Can someone please help me fix this issue? When i click submit it doesnt work!
I think the problem lies in the action="" of the form. Is the route correct?
If it is why it is not working?

These are my routes:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('stocks', 'StockController');    
    Route::get('/stocks/{stock_tag}/doctor','DoctorController@index')->name('stock.doctor');
    Route::get('/stocks/{stock_tag}/doctor/create','DoctorController@create')->name('stock.doctor.create'); 
    Route::post('/stocks/{stock_tag}/doctor/store','DoctorController@store')->name('stock.doctor.store');    
});
```

My store function in DoctorController

```
public function store(Request $request,$stock_tag)
{
    //
    $stock = Stock::find($stock_tag); 
    if(Auth::check()){
            $doctor = Doctor::create([
                'date_of_visit' => $request->input('date_of_visit'),
                'doc_name' => $request->input('doc_name'),
                'remarks' => $request->input('remarks'),
                'description' => $request->input('description'),                                 
                'tag' => $stock->tag_no
            ]);               

            if($doctor){
                 return redirect()->route('stocks.doctor.index', ['doctor'=> $doctor->tag])             
                ->with('success' , 'Visit created successfully');
            }                
    }        
    return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new Visit');
}
```

This is my view:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('stock.doctor.store',$stock->tag_no) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-inline">
        <label for="date">Date of Visit</label>
        <input type="date" name="date_of_visit" max="2030-12-31">                     
    </div> 

    <div class="form-inline">
      <label for="doc_name">Doctor Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="doc_name">          
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <label for="remarks">Remarks </label>
      <input type="text" name="remarks">          
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <label for="description">Medication and Execution </label>
      <input type="text" name="description">          
    </div>       
  </form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
        value="Submit"/>      
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part in the form since you are not sending any files to server.

Comment: well i just copy pasted from another view thats why... but still it should work rite?

Comment: its not even showing an error thats what im stuck

Comment: Have you tried debugging this with `DevTools`? What will the `URL` be in the source code? Also, have you tried removing the `CSRF` for testing purposes?

Comment: No i havent tried those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to place button inside the form XD!!